# Lua reimplementations of PGF math?

Tags: luatex, pgfmath

I was looking around in the texmf-dist tree for TeXLive 2016 on my system and found an implementation of the `pgfmath` functions in Lua, bundled in the (undocumented) PGF library `luamath` in this directory `2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/luamath`.

Using that library instead of `fpu` or `pgfmath` seems to work, and it produces the correct answers to a much higher precision, but there's no mention of it anywhere in the documentation. **EDIT** here's a code snippet from the document I'm working on:

```
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[%
  create col/assign/.code={%
    \pgfluamathparse{ln(\thisrow{vtitre})}
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfmathresult
  },
]{lnvtitre}\titretable
```

Is this library ready for use, or an experimental new feature? Luatex is itself still considered experimental, but I've been using it for the last year without issues.

Comment: I did some preliminary work on `luamath` then Mark Wibrow gave me a large (master)piece of code that I integrated into the existent code. It remained as is for a year or so. Then Christian Feuersänger took the existent code and modified it so that it works (much better), especially with `pgfplots`. There is a mention of it in the pgfplots manual (section 6.3.1). So the answer must be: it is not an official library but it must work, at least in `pgfplots`.

Comment: Oh ok. That would explain why rendering graphs is so much faster now than what it used to be. I'm effectively using these private functions as a replacement for `pgfmathparse` in table modifications. Hopefully they'll get integrated into the next version of TikZ.

Comment: LuaTeX is not beta software any more: version 1.0.0 has been released a few days ago: [Luatex 1.0.0 announcement](http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2016-September/006201.html)

Comment: @egreg But most of us are probably still using the beta ;).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `luamath` library is actively used in pgfplots: if you write `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` (or newer) and translate the document with `lualatex`, `pgfplots` will shift lots of its arithmetics to lua (higher precision, much faster). The reference documentation for this part is in the `pgfplots` manual keyword `lua backend`.

The standalone version of the library is also available as `\usepgflibrary{luamath}`. This enables `\pgfluamathparse{<expression>}` as you found out on your own. In addition, it allows to say

```
\pgfkeys{luamath=parser}
```

in which case it will *substitute* `\pgfmathparse`.

The luamath parser support all (or almost all?) math functions known to `pgf`. In order to also support TeX register- and dimension arithmetics (like `\count0` or `10pt`), it supports a TeX fallback: it tries to compute it in LUA, if that turns out to be impossible, it computes it in TeX.

It also supports `\pgfkeys{luamath/output format=fixed|float}` where `float` is the format understood by `\usepgflibrary{fpu}` (also by `\pgfmathprintnumber`).

There is also a LUA API which does not need the TeX macro as entry point, but that is somewhat beyond the scope of this answer.

The library will become part of the official documentation eventually.

---

There are other choices (like `luamath=only computation`) which are *untested* and *experimental*.

Comment: So, when using pgfplots + context-mkiv, the lua backend will be used automatically?

Comment: yes, provided you use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` or newer