# How to prevent loss of precision for operations on length values?

Tags: calculations, pgfmath

Value `\MM` is equal to `1mm` and is internally stored as `2.84526pt`. Value `\MMQUARTER` is equal to `0.25mm` and is supposed to be stored as `0.711315pt` (`2.84526/4 = 0.711315`) but is stored as `0.7113pt`. I need to find a solution to prevent the truncation of `0.000015`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\MM}{1mm}
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\MMQUARTER}{0.25mm}

        \path node[align=left]
            {%
                \pgfmathparse
                    {% 'MM' IS 2.84526
                        \MM
                    }   \pgfmathresult
                    % NEXT LINE CAN BE IGNORED
                    \hspace{0.33cm} = 1mm
                    \\ % NEW LINE

                \pgfmathparse
                    {% 'MMQUARTER' MUST BE 0.711315 BUT IS 0.7113
                        \MMQUARTER
                    }   \pgfmathresult
                    % NEXT 3 LINES CAN BE IGNORED
                    \hspace{0.5cm} $\approx$ 0.25mm;
                    \\ % NEW LINE
                    \hspace{1.5cm} must be 0.7113\textcolor{red}{15} (exactly 0.25mm)
            };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I don't think there's much you can do about it. If you need `0.711315pt`, better set `0.711315pt` and not `0.25mm`. This has nothing to do with PGF maths, I don't think. It is just a limitation of TeX. `\newdimen\mydim \mydim=0.25mm` also sets a dimension register to `0.7113pt`. And PGF uses the standard means for dimensions, even if you load `fixedpointarithmetic`, while anything you do in `fpu` has to be translated back into the regular stuff for PGF, so I think you'd have the same issue there, though I'm not sure.

Comment: If you set `0.711315pt` you'll get `0.71132pt`, because it is rounding to 5dp anyway.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135534/increasing-precision-in-pgfmathsetmacro, including the links in the question (which may be more helpful than this particular Q&A itself). Lua might be an option: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196171/inaccurate-pgf-calculation or, possibly, use `pgfplots` to replace `\pgfmathparse` with a Lua version, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333633/lua-reimplementations-of-pgf-math.

Comment: However, I only get `0.711304pt` with Lua. But that's probably due to use of `\pgfmathsetlength` rather than `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first sentence is a bit misleading

> Value \MM is equal to 1mm and is internally stored as 2.84526pt

TeX (almost) never uses floating point arithmetic, and never uses it at a place where any difference in machine arithmetic would be detectable from within TeX.

Almost all arithemtic is exact integer arithmetic with decimal conversion just for display purposes.

TeX uses the conversion 25.4mm=1in=72.27pt, 65536sp=1pt

so 1mm is 186467sp and it is this integer that is stored for the length

dividing by 4 and rounding down gets 46616sp which is displayed as 0.7113pt.

You can see the values interactively by running tex on the commandline:

```
$ tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=tex)
**\dimen0=1mm

*\count0=\dimen0

*\showthe\count0
> 186467.
<*> \showthe\count0

? 

*\divide\count0 by 4

*\showthe\count0
> 46616.
<*> \showthe\count0

? 

*\dimen0=\count0 sp

*\showthe\dimen0
> 0.7113pt.
<*> \showthe\dimen0

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

Comment: TeX is truncating, rather than rounding, IIRC.

Comment: @egreg well yes that's what I meant by rounding down, terminology being a bit variable here (it rounds towards zero rather than down, really) which is also known as truncating.

Comment: I think the answer is a bit misleading as it suggest that `0.25mm` is handled as one- quarter of a `mm`. Although this does work with other units, it appears a bit coincidental. I found the example of `0.0125in` which is not the same as division of `1in` by `80` (truncating): `59189sp` for `\dimexpr0.0125in` versus `59203sp` for dividing `1in` by `80`. Even simpler: try `0.1in` and compare with dividing `1in` by `10` (`473657sp` vs `473628sp`)

Comment: @jfbu yes I may reword a bit, mostly I just wanted to point out that tex is using integer arithmetic not floating point. It's true that `.25\somelength` isn't always same as `\divide\somelength by 4` (and I showed one when the question had the other...)

Comment: yes I took your answer as starting point as you had already pointed out the most important which is that internally, integers are used, not floating point operations.

Answer (score 7):

Let me first comment on the comments in your code

```
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\MM}{1mm}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\MMQUARTER}{0.25mm}

                {% 'MM' IS 2.84526
                    \MM

                {% 'MMQUARTER' MUST BE 0.711315 BUT IS 0.7113
                    \MMQUARTER
```

I assume that `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` boils down internally at some point to standard TeX. A dimension specification like `0.25mm` is parsed this way. I will describe it in terms not corresponding one-by-one to the TeX processing but producing exactly equivalent result.

1. first `0.25` is *rounded* to an integral multiple `N/65536`. Here this is an exact match `N=16384`.
2. then a conversion factor is applied, which in the case of the `mm` unit is (according to `tex.web §458`) `7227/2540`. This means that TeX evaluates the *truncation to an integer* of the exact fraction `16384*7227/2540`.

   Now:

   ```
   $ rlwrap etex
   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/MacPorts 2017_1) (preloaded format=etex)
    restricted \write18 enabled.
   **xintexpr.sty
   entering extended mode
   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xintexpr.sty
   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xintfrac.sty
   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xint.sty
   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xintcore.sty
   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xintkernel.sty))))
   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xint/xinttools.sty))
   *\message{\xinttheiexpr [40] 16384*7227/2540\relax}
   46616.9952755905511811023622047244094488188976 
   *\bye
   No pages of output.
   Transcript written on xintexpr.log.
   ```

   So in this case TeX will obtain `46616` and we see that it makes here a relatively big error.
3. The conclusion is that `0.25mm` is stored internally as `46616sp` where `1sp` is the `65536th` part of a (TeX) `pt`.

For more details see [Why pdf file cannot be reproduced?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338297/why-pdf-file-cannot-be-reproduced/338510#338510)

Then, what happens when a dimension internally stored as `46616sp` is displayed using `\the` ? The algorithm is in `§103` of `tex.web` and is a bit subtle. We want to produce a value in `pt` unit which would re-produce exactly the `46616sp` if *rounded* to an integral multiple of `1/65536`. Of course first we handle the integer part, which here vanishes. So let's assume we have some initial `n` with `0 <= n < 65536`. Knuth actually considers (indirectly) the decimal expansion of `(n + 0.5)/65536`. Let's say we look at the first `K` digits of this decimal expansion, so, for `K = 1, 2, 3, 4` and at most `5`, we have

```
(n+0.5)/65536 = D_K/10^K + N_K/(10^K \times 65536)
```

where actually `N_K` for those `K` considered is an *integer*, positive, and strictly less than `65536` (power of two considerations justify some of my assertions). The `N_K` are simply obtained by repeated multiplication by `10` modulo `65536`. The equation above gives

```
65536 D_K/10^K = n + 0.5 - N_K/10^K
```

and if for any `K` we observe that `0< N_K <= 10^K` (positivity is known), the *rounding* of `65536 D_K/10^K` will give back the `n` as expected. This might happen for `K = 1`, ... or `4`. Imagine it did not. Then it will necessarily at `K = 5` but this case is handled especially. If we reach `K = 5` it is because we had `N_4 > 10000`. Then let's `M_5 = 10 N_4 - 50000 + 32768`. It is `> 65536`, so we write `M_5 = q 65536 + r` where `q` is a digit. After simplification we obtain

```
n = 65536 (10 D_4 + q)/100000 + (r - 32768)/100000
```

and with `D_5 = 10 D_4 + q` which has a fifth digit, we again get a decimal `D_5/100000` whose rounding as integral multiple of `1/65536` produces `n/65536`. (I will have to read again `§103` of `tex.web` but this is my impression of what it boils down to).

We can follow the steps for `n = 46616`. First we compute `10(46616.5) = 466165 = 7x65536+7413` which gives use `N_1 = 7413`. It is not `<= 10`, so algorithm continues. First digit was `7`.

```
Python 3.5.4 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Aug 14 2017, 12:43:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> divmod(74130,65536)
(1, 8594)
>>> divmod(85940,65536)
(1, 20404)
>>> divmod(204040,65536)
(3, 7432)
```

thus digits are `7`, `1`, `1`, `3`,  and here we reach `N_4 = 7432` which is less than `10000`. Algorithm stops here and TeX thus produces `0.7113pt`.

From the description above you see it will never produce 6 digits after decimal mark such as `0.711315`. To obtain this you must use a math engine (possibly implemented in macros; since e-TeX of 1999 with `\numexpr` it is easier to do this expandably, at least theoretically) able to handle decimal numbers like those.

You can use `\xinttheiexpr [D]` macro for such computations where `D` is the asked-for number of digits after decimal mark of final result, but computations are done exactly.

---

Going back to the quarter of millimeter (using Plain TeX, works in LaTeX too with `\usepackage{xintexpr}`):

```
\input xintexpr.sty

\xintdefvar mm:= 7227/2540;

\edef\MYQUARTERMM{\xinttheexpr trunc(0.25mm, 40)\relax}

\show\MYQUARTERMM

\bye
```

produces in the log

```
> \MYQUARTERMM=macro:
->0.7113188976377952755905511811023622047244.
l.7 \show\MYQUARTERMM
```

This shows by the way that the meaning of `0.711315` as arising in the original question isn't that clear.

From the above, an a priori  closer 6 digits approximation is `0.711319pt`. After checking one sees though that both `0.711319pt` and `0.711315pt` get converted by TeX into the internal representation `46617sp` (`\number\dimexpr 0.711319pt\relax`, `\number\dimexpr 0.711315pt\relax`).

And `\the\dimexpr 0.711319pt\relax` outputs `0.71132pt`. Thus `0.71132pt` is the most accurate 5 digits representation (after testing it is the only one giving `46617sp` internally) of the actual exact `0.25mm` dimension. However as explained above, when TeX encounters `0.25mm` it will obtain `46616sp`. Using the bigger `cm` unit as in `0.025cm` gives a greater loss of precision (`46605sp`).

Comment: technical note: "rounding" means "with ties going away from zero". In other contexts "rounding" in numerical algorithms may mean "with ties going to even". But here `10.5` rounded means `11` not `10`.

Comment: rant: division in `\numexpr` "rounds" in the sense of my previous comment; but TeX division (`\divide`) *truncates*. In nine cases of out of ten, the rounding done by ``/`` in `\numexpr` has proved a nuisance in my experience, but well.

Comment: One can prove that Knuth algorithms, if starting with `0.x pt`, `0.xy pt`, `0.xyz pt` or `0.xyzt pt` where the last digit is non-zero, going to a dimen register and back to `<decimal>pt` using `\the` always reproduce exactly the initial specification. This is wrong starting with 5 digits. Of course with 6 digits or more, we know this is wrong because the procedure gives in the end at most 5 digits after decimal mark. In the case of 5 digits, examples such as `0.63001pt` or `0.28999pt` show that the input is not necessarily reproduced.